# Do all Vedic mantras start with "hari om"?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda

I've seen Sri sukta starting with hari om, do other mantras of vedas also start with "hari om"

Does it have another meaning.

Comment: I asked "do" what's with the downvotes? Seriously.

Answer (score 11):

No Vedic Mantras start with "Harihi Om". It is not required to do so.

But, there is a rule by which all Vedic recitals must start and finish with the Pranava or OM.

> BrahmAnah pranavah kuryAd AdAv ante cha sarvadA |
>  Svatyanokritam
>   purva parastAch cha vishiryati ||
>
> Manu Smriti 2.74. Let him always pronounce the syllable Om at the
>   beginning and at the end of (a lesson in) the Veda; (for) unless the
>   syllable Om precede (the lesson) will slip away (from him), and unless
>   it follow it will fade away.

As regards the Sri Sukta from Khila of Rig Veda, then i can tell which Mantras are actually part of it.

Sri Sukta is comprised of 15 Rik Mantras.

Mantra 1 starts with

> " Hiranyavarnam harinim suvarna rajatasrajAm |"

and, the last Mantra or Mantra 15 starts with

> "tAm ma A vaha jAtavedo lakshmi-manapagAminim.."

So, any other Mantras, Slokas etc that are added before or after the Sri Sukta are additional stuffs. They are not officially part of the Sukta itself.

Comment: The last mantra you posted is "टाम् म आ वह जातवेदो लक्श्मिम् अनपगामिनिम्।" but correct mantra is "तां म॒ आव॑ह॒ जात॑वेदो ल॒क्षीमन॑पगा॒मिनी॓म्" whose transliteration is tAM ma Avaha jAta vedo lakShImanapagAminI॓m. As they are mantras, they should be transliterated properly. Will you do it properly or shall I?

Comment: "As they are mantras, they should be transliterated properly" -- No not required.. i am not requesting someone to chant these mantras by taking them from my answer.. so differentiating between the m's and Bindus are not essential.. I won't edit u should not edit either..@Sarvabhouma

Comment: I am not talking about bindis. It is about the mantras. When we are transliterating non english words, we should use language which is understandable to everyone. Many users thought such incomplete transliteration is gibberish or a typos. Better to use complete or no tranlisteration at all. Just changing A looks like a typo. You are giving the wrong mantra. If we are giving an answer or question, there should be a clear understanding. If you are not saying to chant the mantra, why to add the wrong mantra? Why don't you delete it? and You can't say I should not edit it.

Comment: It is not Bindi it is Bindu.. If i am giving wrong mantras then let me check again.. it can happen because i type manually from books..@Sarvabhouma

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I have checked again.. i typed the mantra correctly..nothing wrong..

Comment: I am saying that you transliterated completely. According to the transliteration you used, it is giving a totally a wrong mantra rather than what is said in the Veda. टाम् म आ वह जातवेदो लक्श्मिम् अनपगामिनिम् is not the last mantra.

Comment: I said the last Mantra **starts with**..i did not say it is the whole mantra.... the concluding part is of course " vindeyam purushAn aham" .. giving the full mantra is not required for this answer.. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: I have slightly modified the transliteration if OP is okay

Answer (score 2):

Vedic Mantras star with 'AUM'(Om) and not 'Hari Om'. The Mantras conclude with 'Om Shanti' or some other invocation with 'Om'. Manu Smriti enjoins that all invocations of the Brahaman should commence and end with the holy sound 'AUM'.

Comment: Isn't this already mentioned by Rickross in the other answer?

Comment: You should cite sources.