# Should Stotras and Mantras be recited aloud?

Tags: scripture, mantras, stotra

Should Stotras, such as Ganpati Stotra, Durga Stotra, etc., and Mantras be recited aloud or can they be recited just in mind? Also, does the absolute correct pronunciation of words in Stotras matter?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate which @Rickross has answered already!

Comment: No @AkshayS I had only answered for mantra japa .. for stotras I did not answer previously .. stotra recital must be done loudly, quite contrary to mantra japa

Comment: We should recite a stotra aloud mainly because it is a hymn to praise a deity? When you praise someone, it should be done out loud?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Stotras

Stotras should never be recited in mind. In Stotras' case there should be loud recital.

In Mantra Japa, the best form is Manasa Japa (the silent chant). Loud Mantra Japa is considered as the inferior kind of Japa.

> **Manasaa yah smaret stotram** vachashaa vaa manum japet |
>  **Ubhayam nishphalam devi** bhinna-bhaandokadam yathaa ||
>
> O Devi! The act of reciting Stotras in mind and the act of repeating Mantras loudly are both fruitless just as is the act of storing water in a pot which has a hole in it.
>
> **Kularanava Tantram 15.57**

### Mantras

For Mantras, the rule is exactly the opposite as already shown [in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22637/4732).

> Ucchair japohadhamah prokta upaanshur madhyamah smritah |
>  Uttamo
>   mAnaso devi trividhah kathitah japah ||
>
> O Goddess, the loud japa is considered as the worst kind, the
>   whispering japa (upanshu) is the middling kind and the japa that is
>   done completely in the mind (maanasa), is the best form of japa. These
>   three are said to be the kinds of japa.
>
> **Kularnava Tantram 15.55**

That's why Stotra recital must always be done loudly.

The rules for reciting Mantras are many many and all of them can not be covered in one answer. In comparison, rules of Stotra recital are only a few and simple to follow.

The following verses are from the Varaahi Tantram, quoted in both Tantrasaarah and Ahnik Krityam:

> Pranavanchaadime datvaa stotram vaa samhitaam pathet |
>  ante cha
>   pranavam pranavm dadyaadi-tyuvaachaadi-purushah ||
>  Stotre cha
>   samhitaayaancha shlokamantyam dviruccharet |
>  **Manasaa na smaret
>   pathedakaagramaanasah ||**
>
> One should chant OM before and after reciting a Stotra or a Samhitaa.
>   And, **one should never recite Stotra in mind; one should recite it
>   loudly with a concentrated mind.**

Comment: By mantras you certainly mean beej mantras @Rickross

Comment: i think the OP asks for the general mantras like dhyana and pranama mantras and these can be chanted aloud

Comment: Dhyana sloka etc one shd chant loudly .. also, no, my answer is not only about Bija mantra, even for Vedic mantras it is applicable @Pratimaputra

Comment: @Pratimaputra See the manu Smriti verse quoted in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22637/4732) .. Manu of course is talking about Vedic mantras

Comment: Nice information, could you please explain What is the difference between a stotra and mantra whenever free? Can Rama Nama japa be considered as a mantra or stotra? Abs something like a Hanuman chalisa or ram raksha Stotram? Thanks in advance. If you want this to be a question on the main site for everyone to benefit I don’t mind.

Comment: Hanuman Chalisa, Ram Raksha Stotra are examples of Stutis or Stotras. Sometimes a Stotra can be a Mantra too. Rama nama japa is technically different from Mantra Japa. It is a different type called Nama Japa.@Archit

Comment: thank you, just to clarify, stotra is any song or verse sung in praise like Chalisa and Ram Raksha. How would one differentiate a mantra? Eg of mantra? As per the above tantra, must nama Japa be done orally or mentally?

Comment: Every Stotra or Mantra will have a Viniyoga associated with it. From which we can tell which is which. Other than that Mantras are of course very short compared to Stotras which are composed of Slokas. A Mantra that has more than 20 syllables is called Mala Mantras. Some Stotras are Mantras at the same time. Such Stotras are Mala Mantras because any Stotra obviously will have 20 or more syllables. Devi Khadgamala Stotra is a Mantra and a Stotra at the same time. Budha Stotra (composed of 25 names of Budha) is a Stotra and mantra (the Viniyoga itself mentions that).

Comment: @ArchitNama Japa is more close to Mantra Japa than Stotra Japa. So it can be done loudly or silently both.

Comment: @Archit You can also check the answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/41098/what-is-meant-by-kavacha

Comment: thank you very much, If one doesn’t know the Viniyoga, thinks a mantra is a stotra and chants it (obviously it’ll be fruitless since he has not been initiated). What is that aspect which differentiates a stotra from a mantra, which even the Rishis who wrote Viniyoga used to say that ha this is a mantra? Is it the length and number of syllables? But then again as you said a long stotra may also be a mantra. 2. Can the differentiation be based on What objective they respectively accomplish? 3. Next question—> When should one chant a stotra vs when should one chant a mantra

Comment: It is difficult to differentiate based on criteria. But most times it is obvious which is what. Stotras are usually always Stuti (that is praising the Deity). But Mantras don't need to have that feature. From the Viniyoga portion we can know which is what clearly. @Archit

Comment: cool thanks a lot!

Comment: The last paragraph says that (One should chant 'Om' before and after reciting a stotra.) Om is a mantra right ? So what about the people who are not initiated? And many times I have seen people reciting stotras but they don't chant 'Om' . So is it wrong ? Will that stotra be of no use? Is it compulsory to chant 'Om' ?

Comment: Those who are not initiated can either say Namah or aum in place of Om. @LSSJBroly

Comment: Yes you can say its wrong .. Om is called the Setu .. just like a dam prevents water from getting dispersed and hence wasted Om plays a similar role here .. if Om is not chanted then the benefits earned from the recital get lost .. Similar rule is there in case of Vedic recitals too. See this answer (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24418/4732) Manu 2.74 @LSSJBroly

Comment: {Those who are not initiated can either say Namah or aum in place of Om.}   Thanks , Namah and Aum are not any kind of mantras right? And could you also tell me the source of this statement if possible.

Comment: Aum and Namaha are of course mantras that's why they can substitute OM in this application. But they can be chanted by anyone without initiation (unlike Om and other mantras). That namah can be chanted by anyone can be shown from Smritis. AUM is called the Tantrokta pranava. Lord Shiva says anyone (including Sudras) can always chant it. @LSSJBroly

Comment: Ahh..actually I was asking about the source of this statement (The non initiated people can chant Namaha or Aum before and after reciting a stotra)

Comment: I told you the source already .. Tantras. In any application where OM is used uninitiated should say AUM or namah as they are not allowed to say OM @LSSJBroly this rule is quoted in various books like Shaktananda Tarangini and Anhika Krityam

Comment: Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 2):

According to the Stavakusumajnali published by Nagpur Ramakrishna Math

> stotras are part of vachik (vocal) puja (worship) called 'Bangmoyee puja' and should be chanted with correct chhanda and pronunciation and audible clear voice, understanding the meanings of the stotras and contemplating on the 'bhava' (page 4-5).

For those who are are able to pronounce correctly but have devotion, the scripture says

> murkho vadati vishnaya dhiro vadati vishnave/ubhayos tulyam artham cha bhavagrAhi janArdanah (Narada-pancharatra)

meaning that the uneducated one says visnaya and the learned says vishnave.To God both are the same as He accepts the devotion alone.

Answer (score 0):

Samarth Ramdas swami says, you should  say name of lord ram loudly

> **Jani Bhojani Naam Vache vadave ATI Adare Gadya ghoshe mhanave Harichintanene ann jewit jave Tari shri hari pavijeto swabhave**

*While wandering in the masses, and while consuming food, recite the name of lord Ram
Recite it with respect, clarity and loudly
You should consume your food while thinking about God
By following this you can attain god*

Saarth Manache Shlok, Shlok #89