What are the Stotras and ruling deities of the Navagrahas?
Sometimes the Navagrahas have a bad influence on a persons life. To pacify these planets what are the stotrams of each of the Navagrahas that can be chanted by the house holders. What are the conditions to recite them . Also provide the name of the deities and mahavidyas governing each grahas from an authentic source. Thank you.

For such stotras see this page --- https://www.hindupedia.com/en/Stotra#Prayers_addressed_to_Planet_Devatas

Stotras should be recited sitting on an a mat facing either North or the East. Stotrams have to recited loudly only (unlike Mantras) Cleanliness should be maintained too. See -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33848/4732

Ruling deities for the planetary deities are as follows -- Matangi (Sun),Bhuvaneswari (Moon), Bagalamukhi (Mars), Shodashi (Mercury),Tara (Jupiter), Kamala (Venus), Kali (Saturn),Chinnamasta (Rahu) and Dhumavati (Ketu).
