Which gives better result - chanting the mantras aloud or chanting it in mind?
I chant the following mantras a number of times but I want the mantras to be more effective . Please can anyone with scriptural reference and some experience tell which will be better for the following mantras ?

Gayatri mantra
Saraswati namastyubham varade kamarupini vidyarambham Karishyami Siddhir Bharati me sada
Saraswati Mahabhage vidyakamala lochane vishwaroope vishalakshi Vidyam dehi namahastute.
Durga dwatrimsha namavali


Chanting mantras in mind gives best result (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22637/4732) but reciting Stotras in mind is not fruitful (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33848/4732)

Yes yes absolutely @Rickross. Recently I have started the mantra japa in mind but one problem is that i am unable to find that level of concentration yet. So just trying to practice and hopefully will be able to get that level of concentration in mental mantra japa.

Yes,doing japa completely in mind is more difficult than chanting loudly ..you can chant in the whispering mode first if chanting completely in mind gives difficulty and then gradually move to the silent japa mode

@Rickross just wanted to make sure are the Saraswati namastyubyam and Saraswati mahabhage one are mantras ?? I have seen them as a part of the stotra , but individually are they mantras? Should I chant them in mind or out aloud??

Technically they are parts of Stotras so they are Shlokas so better to chant them aloud not in mind.

You can chant them in any of the ways below, but what matters is they’re synchronized with your breath. According to Kulārnava Tantram (कुलार्णव तंत्र/குலார்ணவ தந்திரம்) [Sloka: 15.54], there are three types of chanting as given below:
उच्चैरजापोऽधामः प्रोक्तः उपांसुर मध्यमो स्मृतः ।
उत्तमो मानसो देवि! त्रिविध: कथितो जप: ॥ १५.५४॥


Vaikharī (वैखरी) or loud verbal chanting.
Upāmsu (उपांशु) or humming/soft whispering.
Mānasika (मानसिक) or ‘mental’ chants.

You can switch between these chanting styles so that your meditation or japa doesn’t become too monotonous or repetitive. Switching will prevent you from falling asleep as well, especially when you chant in the early hours of the morning.

The best is Mānasika Japa (मानसिक जप/Mental Repetition) which is very efficacious and facilitates to focus on mantra..

