# Are salutations to deities like Ganesha and Hari to start a scripture non-Vedic as Dayanand Saraswati seems to be saying?

Tags: vedas, dayananda-saraswati

https://aryasamaj.davchennai.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Satyarth-Prakash-English.pdf

> In no case do the Vedas and the Shastras begin with" I bow unto Ganesha," etc. Wherever even
> Vedic scholars start with Hari Aum, they have contracted this pernicious habit from the
> Pauraniks* and the Tantriks**. Nowhere in the Vedas and Shastras is the word 'Hari' written in
> the beginning. Hence a book ought start either with Atha (now), or AUM

Comment: Related/Similar post -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24417

Answer (score 1):

Invoking *Gaṇeśa* & *Nārāyaṇa* for benediction in the beginning is a very old practice. Copying a scripture was a ritual in itself. Here is a line from the *Yoginītantra* as quoted *Prāṇatoṣaṇītantra*

> सत्येऽक्षरे स्थितः शम्भुः शूलपाणिस्त्रिलोचनः । प्रजापतिर्द्वापरे च त्रेतायां सूर्य एव च । कृते युगे पिनाकी च कलौ लिप्यक्षरे हरिः ।। आरम्भे च समाप्तौ लेखकं प्रतिपूजयेत् । हरिञ्च गन्धपुष्पाद्यैर्वस्त्रैश्च सुमनोहरैः ।। यावदक्षरसंख्यानं प्रतिपत्रे च सुन्दरि । तावद्युगसहस्राणि ब्रह्मलोके वसेच्चिरम् ।।

> Translation : In the *Satyayuga*, the 3-eyed Lord *Śambhu* wielding the trident & the *Pināka* bow presides over alphabets. In *Tretāyuga* it is *Sūrya*, in *Dvāparayuga* it is  *Prajāpati* & in *Kaliyuga*, it is *Hari* (who is the presiding deity of alphabets). At the beginning & the end (of writing a book), (the patron) should worship the scribe (who was always a *brāhmaṇa*) & *Hari* with articles like scents, flowers, beautiful clothes etc. O Beautiful One ! (By doing so), he gets to live in *Brahmaloka* for as many thousand *yuga*s as the number of alphabets written on each page.

While invoking *Gaṇeśa* to ensure that no obstacles befall the scribe & the patron before completion of the book is understandable.

However, Dayananda Saraswati interpreted it to mean that these traditional benedictory sentences have been forcefully inserted into the main corpus of the text by those whom he referred to as 'blasphemers & heretics' (i.e those who didn't agree with his interpretions), which is not the case.